# "Black Hats out there are a lot craftier than you are" what is the exact meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Recently I've seen the sentence: **Black Hats out there
are a lot craftier than you are**

What is the meaning?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a proverb :)

Black Hats are **black hat hackers**.

> [Black hat - meanings here in the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=black%20hat)

In the computer-world, people who try to find errors in security systems, so they can get to information that is supposed to be hidden, are called *hackers*.

Some of those people do this to tell the owner of the system that they found a security flaw, so that it can be fixed. Those are called *white hats*, or *white hat hackers*.

Those that use the security flaws to steal (and use/abuse) the data, are called *black hats*.

So the sentence means that you should never think too easily that your web site or online application is completely safe, simply because *you* cannot break into it. There are people out there who are a *lot* better at breaking into your application than you are!

Comment: The use of white and black is a cultural reference to the stereotypical colours used to denote good and evil, respectively. In old Western films, for example, the baddie often wears a black hat and the goodie (eg the Lone Ranger) wears a white hat. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1210819/

Comment: @toandfro Ah, that's worth mentioning. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Complete and great meaning. Also I've deleted the proverb tag :)

Comment: Also, **between programmers**, being "hacker" means being able to put quickly working system using uncommon innovative shortcuts (a positive attribute). Black hat hackers are called "crackers", but such subtleties were lost on journalists, and "hacker" has negative connotations for general public. http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/introduction.html